# Not able to update array variable inside the loop for each thread call

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have written the below `Main` function in which I have a `for` loop and I am populating an array of string, and then calling a function using threading. However, my problem is that I am not able wait for the function to complete before iterating further in `for` Loop.

I want the `for` loop to wait until thread 1 completes, so that every time I pass different array to function.

I hope it makes sense what I am trying to achieve from this.

```
private static void Print(string[] FC)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(_myLock);
                Console.WriteLine($"Threading Number {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} starting...");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                foreach (var vc in FC)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(vc.ToString());
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Error_Logging
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_myLock);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String[] FC_Array = new string[4];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    FC_Array[i] = "String Number" + rnd.Next(1, 5);
                }
                System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(async () => await Task.Run(() => Print(FC_Array)));
                thread.Start();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

Output of the above program is as below:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfV8w.png)

Expected Output is to have random number for each time the print method is called in the `for` loop of main class.

Comment: If you need to wait, why use threads?

Comment: Even with multithreading isn't it that we wait for the function/method to complete one process and than carry to the next one so that concurrency issue doesn't takes place ?

Comment: You pass a new array every time already because of the ToArray() call you make. That call makes a new array each loop

Comment: It's difficult to understand your intentions by reading the code. It might be more helpful if you could show a non-parallel version that works correctly, and then ask us for an advice about how it can be parallelized.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I have updated the question to make it more clearer.

Comment: Could you improve the formatting of the code? It's easier to read the code when it is formatted properly, and also when the lines are short so that horizontal scrolling is not required. You can add some line-breaks to reduce the length of long lines, and also minimize the whitespace at the left side.

Comment: Why are you dealing with the low level thread constructs?  You should use Task Parallel Library (TPL) and async/await abstractions in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Always use task class instead of Thread.

It would be better to create a Thread array and in a loop assign the work to the Task and add it into the thread array after the loop run.startAll and waitAll function of thread.

**Code according to your requirement**

```
    private static void Print(string[] FC)
    {
        try
        {
            //System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(_myLock);
            Console.WriteLine($"Threading Number {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} starting...");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            foreach (var vc in FC)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(vc.ToString());
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Error_Logging
        }
        finally
        {
            //System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_myLock);
        }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var FC_Array = new string[4];
        var rnd = new Random();
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                FC_Array[i] = "String Number" + rnd.Next(1, 5);
            }
            await Task.Run(() => Print(FC_Array));
            Console.WriteLine($"task work completed # {j+1}");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Find the output of the above code
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9pvF.png)

**For start thread Execution at the same time then use below code**

**For Example**

```
       var taskList = new List<Task>();
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    taskList.Add(new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); });
}
    taskList.ForEach(task => task.Start());
    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

**Another Example**

```
var taskList = new List<Task>();
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1); });
}

try
{
    Task.WhenAll(taskList).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tasks were cancelled");;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Fazeel . I am not able to understand how can I use this into my code ?

Comment: Ok I'll edit the answer according to your code... Vote me if you like the answer and give me reputation.. Thanks